# Identify usage state of file using readdir

Tags: unix

Using the `readdir` function, how can I identify files that are still in use and not closed? I found that the only indication of this is when the file size is 0 but this may mean that I count an empty file as still in use, while it might not be.

What are other indicators of a file being in use?

Comment: Clarification: When I say "in use", I mean file being created by another process, and not finalised/closed yet. Not concerned about files just being open for "read".

Comment: If this is a process you made yourself, you could have that process store information about its files somewhere, such as in a file index.